# Selecting two fields recursively for each month

Tags: sql

### Indroduction

I'm using `FreeRadius` and I'd like to query my table, `radacct` and select two fields (`datetime` fields) within a given year and provide a `SUM`of `bytes_send` and `bytes_received` per month.

### My database layout

```
fieldtype    fieldname
---------    ----------
varchar      username
datetime     start
datetime     end
bigint       bytes_send
bigint       bytes_received
```

### Database data

```
username    start                  end                      bytes_send    bytes_received
---------   -------------------    -------------------      ----------    --------------
admin       2013-04-22 22:14:34    2013-04-22 22:24:51      8723142       851314
admin       2013-05-14 11:50:50    2013-05-15 11:58:35      11073753      958437
admin       2013-05-14 14:36:24    2013-05-15 15:11:59      869125711     3152551
admin       2013-05-15 20:45:16    2013-05-15 20:47:11      2373753       114857
demo        2013-05-14 23:21:51    2013-05-15 05:32:20      59125919      3815816
```

### Desired output

I'd like to have a query which puts out something like this (the SQL query just needs to know the year (`2013` in this case) and the username (`admin` in this case).

```
username   month  total_bytes
--------   -----  -----------
admin      04     9574456
admin      05     886799062
```

### My solution

I'd probably do this with PHP, I set a year (`2013` in this case) and perform 12 queries (one for each month) using a simple for loop.

### My question

The solution I proposed is probably not the best solution, hence I'd like to know if this could be done with just a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple aggregate will do it

```
SELECT
    username, MONTH(start), SUM(bytes_send+bytes_received)
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
     -- avoiding the YEAR function on a predicate
    start >= '20130101' AND start < '20140101'
    AND
    username = 'admin'
GROUP BY
    username, MONTH(start)
```

Comment: Working perfectly, better than I expected! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   username, TIMEDIFF(start,end), SUM(bytes_send + bytes_received)
FROM
   table
WHERE
   start>='20130101' AND start<'20140101'
```

This'll give the username, timedifference between both dates and the sum of bytes. It's the easiest query to request the data. Add a WHERE to further limit the data you get if you have to.